# Looking for a Docker Maven plugin that supports Java 6

Tags: docker, containers, maven-plugin, java-6

So I wish to create a docker container from my Java 6, Maven project. I tried a whole bunch

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cdocker%20maven%20plugin

but everyone failed with either a

> Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

or

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Is there any plugin that still supports Java 6 out there? Or is there another way to use a maven plugin to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 0):

How about you build it with your project itself. You might have to work out the dependencies.

https://github.com/rhuss/docker-maven-plugin